# I got Call to a member function contains() on null error with Spatie\Permission method

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

In Laravel 8 / livewire 2.5 using Spatie\Permission method :

```
$user = Auth::user();
if ( !$user->can('action') ) {
   ...
```

raise error :

```
Call to a member function contains() on null
pointing to file vendor/spatie/laravel-permission/src/Traits/HasPermissions.php:291, lines : 
    {
        $permissionClass = $this->getPermissionClass();
        if (is_string($permission)) {
            $permission = $permissionClass->findByName($permission, $this->getDefaultGuardName());
        }

        if (is_int($permission)) {
            $permission = $permissionClass->findById($permission, $this->getDefaultGuardName());
        }

        if (! $permission instanceof Permission) {
            throw new PermissionDoesNotExist;
        }

        return $this->permissions->contains('id', $permission->id); // pointing to this line

    }
```

I found branch https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/issues/133 with :

> It would seem that perhaps something in your own application code is
> interfering with $this->permissions. The  usual cause of this is
> creating a permissions property on the User object, which prevents the
> BelongsTo  relationship from being used.

My user model :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
//use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
//use Laravel\Jetstream\HasProfilePhoto;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasRoles;
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
//    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use Notifiable;
//    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
```

It has HasRoles trait and I commented all Fortify\Jetstream and cleared all cahce, but I still got the same error.
My model has no any permissions property, but searching in the project I see that Jetstream has permissions method...

Can it be reason this error and how vcan it be fixed ?

**UPDATED BLOCK** :
This component has no any permission(s) property.
Its header looks like :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;
use App\Models\ItemRoom;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LogoutResponse;
use Livewire\Component;
use DB;

use App\Models\State;
use App\Models\Subregion;
use App\Models\Region;
use App\Models\Item;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\Models\Settings;
use App\Library\CheckValueType;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use App\Library\LayoutType;


class CrudItems extends Component
{
    public $user_search_query;
    public $usersSelectionArray = [];
    public $usersAutocompleteSearchSelectionArray = [];
    public $highlightIndex;
    public $showAutoCompleteSearch= false;

    use WithPagination;

    protected $listeners = ['openItemInEditor' => 'edit', 'addNewItem' => 'add', 'fileUpload' => 'handleFileUpload'];
    public $form
        = [
            'name'         => '',
            'state_id'     => '',
            'region_id'    => '',
            'subregion_id' => '',
            'town'         => '',
            'street_addr'  => '',
            'postal_code'  => '',
            'phone'        => '',

            'feature' => '',


            'image'       => '',
            'source_type' => '',
            'source_url'  => '',
            'youtube_key' => '',
            'created_at'  => '',
            'updated_at'  => '',
            'is_reopen'   => false,
        ];

    public $itemStatusLabelValueArray = [];
    public $statesSelectionArray = [];
    public $regionsSelectionArray = [];
    public $subregionsSelectionArray = [];

    public $selectedState = null;
    public $selectedRegion = null;
    public $selectedSubregion = null;

    public $uploaded_file_name;
    public $uploadedImageFilenameData;
    public $uploadedItemImage;


    public $current_item_id;
    public $filters
        = [
            'name'             => '',
            'filter_operation' => '',
            'status'           => '',
            'state_id'         => '',
            'feature'          => '',
        ];
    public $updateMode = 'browse';

    public function render()
    {
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the second code block called from?

Comment: from render() method of livewire Component

Comment: Does that component have a $this->permissions property? what properties does it have?

Comment: Please read UPDATED BLOCK

Comment: Neither Jetstream, fortify or sanctum should interfere with spatie permissions. That looks more like an error coming from the model. Can we see the full User class? Are you using custom Role/Persmission model classes? Also, does `Auth::user()` in the render method, is actually returning a User model ?

Comment: Thanks for hints. I checked and found permissions property I missed. It is salved.